# How can I access a secret value from an Azure Pipelines expression?

Tags: azure-pipelines

I have two different Azure Pipeline accounts, one with secret variables set, and one without any variables set.

In a `script` task, I would like to have the secret variables available. The documentation suggests to pass them like this:

```
  env:
    MY_MAPPED_ENV_VAR: $(mySecret)
```

However, if I'm running my pipeline in the account without the variables set, `MY_MAPPED_ENV_VAR` is set to `$(mySecret)`.
How can I define the environment variables so that `MY_MAPPED_ENV_VAR` is empty (or not set) if `$(mySecret)` is not available.

I tried the following approaches:

- `MY_MAPPED_ENV_VAR: ${{variables.mySecret}}` (value is always empty)
- `MY_MAPPED_ENV_VAR: ${{variables['mySecret']}}` (value is always empty)
- `MY_MAPPED_ENV_VAR: ${{mySecret}}` (syntax error)
- `MY_MAPPED_ENV_VAR: $[variables.mySecret]` (value is set to `$[variables.mySecret]` if secret is not available, even though docs state that value renders to "not set" when variable not found)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try [conditionally assign a variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#conditional-insertion):

```
variables:
  mySecret1: $[variables.mySecret]

steps:    
- powershell: |
    Write-Host "This works: $(mySecret1)"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is indeed solving my problem!

Comment: For anybody interested seeing the full solution, here's the commit fixing the issue: https://github.com/apache/flink/commit/b226cbd1f595b405f5da376fa3d22e1850fbf4e1